# Lucene-Style query string Elasticsearch PHP

Tags: php, elasticsearch, query-string

I have searched for days how to query data from Elasticsearch with an array as parameter or with JSON formaat like showing on this page http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/php-api/current/_quickstart.html
But not with a lucene-style query string. Is there any way to query data from Elasticsearch using lucene-style query string with Elasticsearch PHP Client API, like (type:apache-access OR type:apache-error)?

Comment: Have you considered using another Elasticsearch PHP Client? like [Elastica](https://github.com/ruflin/Elastica)?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you can do this via the Elasticsearch basic query via uri:

http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-uri-request.html

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/twitter/tweet/_search?q=user:kimchy'
```

A bit of discussion on it (including the fact that it supports Lucene style queries) here:

http://okfnlabs.org/blog/2013/07/01/elasticsearch-query-tutorial.html

> Querying Basic Queries Using Only the Query String
>
> Basic queries can be done using only query string parameters in the
>   URL. For example, the following searches for text ‘hello’ in any field
>   in any document and returns at most 5 results:

```
{endpoint}/_search?q=hello&size=5
```

> Basic queries like this have the advantage that they only involve
>   accessing a URL and thus, for example, can be performed just using any
>   web browser. However, this method is limited and does not give you
>   access to most of the more powerful query features.
>
> Basic queries use the q query string parameter which supports the
>   Lucene query parser syntax and hence filters on specific fields (e.g.
>   fieldname:value), wildcards (e.g. abc*) and more.
>
> There are a variety of other options (e.g. size, from etc) that you
>   can also specify to customize the query and its results. Full details
>   can be found in the ElasticSearch URI request docs.